# DAX - MIN/MAX +Filter/Calculate

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

This is very much a follow-up question to a previous query. My data looks like this, only the "Active" working time is documented per ID, per separate working area, the "Standing" time is not.

| ID | Working Area | Date | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Area1 | 23/4/22 | 08:00 | 08:41 |
| 123 | Area2 | 23/4/22 | 09:00 | 09:55 |
| 123 | Area3 | 24/4/22 | 11:45 | 16:30 |
| 125 | Area1 | 24/5/22 | 13:14 | 14:55 |
| 125 | Area2 | 25/5/22 | 05:20 | 06:22 |

Clarification:

- ID:123 was started at 08:00 and ended at 16:30, a day later.
- The total active time is: 381 Minutes
- The total standing time is: 950 Minutes

Required result:

- Where ID is the same, the difference between the previous Endtime and the next Starttime.
- A Measure where the selection of multiple entries per ID considers all the difference between all entries selected, not just the MIN and MAX values of selected entries
- The possibility to limit the first possible Start to a miniumum specific time (e.g. 0400) and to a maximum end time (e.g. 1800). This serves the purpose of preventing the total time running overnight and creating a false Standingtime (no work happens overnight). This is only a consideration when the Job/ID is started and ended on different dates

Thus far I've tried a Self-Join with a shifting index on the "Start" and "End" times, and while this work, the computing time required to generate Standing Time is not workable. Now I think that a measure or calculate column is the correct way to go, but I have no idea where to start with it. Any pointers?